# How to upgrade when conda-forge installs an old version

Tags: python, command-line, anaconda, package, conda

`pandas-profiling` (appears to be) a delightful little package that improves on the `pd.DataFrame.describe()` method. I decided to install it using `conda`, and, as per the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/), I input `conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling` on the command line.

Here's where it gets wonky. The current build of `pandas-profiling` is 2.8.0. This is the text that returned on the command line:

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    pandas-profiling-1.4.1     |                0          39 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:          39 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  pandas-profiling   conda-forge/osx-64::pandas-profiling-1.4.1-0
```

...Version 1.4.1? That doesn't seem right. I'll likely be missing out on some significant functionality. I'd like to upgrade, but, being the neophyte data scientist I am, I'm not familiar enough with `conda` as a package manager to either figure out why the latest build on `conda-forge` is 1.4.1 or how to upgrade, either via `pip` or `conda` (ideally via conda, for the sake of consistency).

I then investigated the builds with `conda search pandas-profiling --info`, which revealed the following about the `1.4.1_0` build that appeared to install:

```
pandas-profiling 1.4.1 0
------------------------
file name   : pandas-profiling-1.4.1-0.tar.bz2
name        : pandas-profiling
version     : 1.4.1
build       : 0
build number: 0
size        : 39 KB
license     : MIT
subdir      : osx-64
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64/pandas-profiling-1.4.1-0.tar.bz2
md5         : 9a23538636bc7bcc05c6e7a90bca3c33
constraints :
  - pypy <0a0
dependencies:
  - jinja2 >=2.8
  - matplotlib >=1.4
  - pandas >=0.19
  - python >=2.7
  - six >=1.9
```

This was built for Python 2.7, but my `conda` is managing for version 3.7.6!

Does anyone have any insight into what's going on here and how I can upgrade to the latest build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this, it's likely that there is some incompatibility between the dependencies of your current environment and the dependencies of the new package (`pandas-profiling`), at least according to the most recent version of the package.

But apparently conda was able to find an older version of the package that has looser requirements (possibly due to a bug in that old package's metadata), so it decided to give you that version instead.

To specify the exact version you're looking for, try one of the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling=2.8
conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling=2.8.0
```

If that fails, try this, just to see what it brings along with it:

```
conda create -n testenv -c conda-forge pandas-profiling=2.8.0 python=3.7
```

Try installing its dependencies one at a time into your preferred environment (specifying versions) and see which one fails to install.  That may give a clue about where the incompatibility comes from.

Using `conda search --info` (as you did) is also a good way to to figure out what's going on with the dependencies.  But if you discover any problems with the package, or you need other details w.r.t. how it was built, the recipe for conda-forge's `python-profiling` package can be found [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/pandas-profiling-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/meta.yaml).

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with dependencies as you suggest. This issue occurs even when you create a new clean environment and try to install pandas-profiling as the the first package.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior.  When I try it on my Mac, it works as expected.  `conda create -n foo`; `conda activate foo`; `conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling`; It seems to work.  Are you on a different OS?

Comment: Yes, it's on a different OS from Mac. It's Windows 10

Comment: @Princy OK, If you think there is a problem with the conda package on windows, it may be worthwhile creating an issue on the [pandas-profiling-feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/pandas-profiling-feedstock/issues).  Perhaps one of the package maintainers is willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

How I solved this was by making sure conda was updated before trying to install pandas-profiling. And it was in a new environment.

Create a new environment:

`conda create -n new_env`

Install conda in it (it should be the latest version by default, but verify and update it if necessary):

`conda activate new_env`

`conda install conda`

Install pandas-profiling:

`conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling`

An up-to-date conda was the key. Also, when pandas-profiling (outdated version) was already installed in the environment, uninstalling and reinstalling didn't work.